# Is this Secure: Encryption Algorithm using SHA256

Tags: python, security, encryption, hash, sha

I am trying to create an encryption algorithm that uses SHA256 to generate the stream that it should XOR the data with.
I want to know the following code provides a secure encryption algorithm.

The following algorithm is used for both encryption and decryption.

```py
def crypt(content: bytes, key) -> bytes:
    out = []
    for i in range(0, len(content), 32):
        hasher = hashlib.sha256()
        hasher.update(key)
        hasher.update(b"FME&$#^01 is some tasty salt.")
        hasher.update(str(i).decode())
        block = content[i:i+32]
        digest = hasher.digest()

        for d in range(len(block)):
            out.append(block[d] ^ digest[d])
    return bytes(out)
```

Edit: it wasn't; I forgot to update the hash with the current position, this makes the XOR repeat and if you know the first 32 bytes you could decrypt the entire string. I fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is extremely insecure.

The value of `digest` will have the exact same value every time through the loop.  You are repeatedly xor'ing your contents with the same 32 bytes.  You have created a Vigenere cipher, which can be easily cracked.

You could make your cipher more secure by adding `str(i).encode()` to the input of the hasher.  You need something to change the value of digest on each round in an unpredictable manner.

I'm not a good enough cryptographer to promise you this new version is secure. But it's not trivial to break.

---

Update.  Two important things I need to add.

First, your algorithm is only secure if you use a different key every time. If you are communicating multiple times with the same user, you must re-negotiate a session key each time. Your program is generating a one-time pad, and reusing a one time pad is fatal.  Alternatively, prepend a 32-byte random IV to each message, and use that IV as part of the key.  That forces every session to generate a different stream.

Second, I assume you're playing around and having fun. Under no circumstances should you use this for actual production code. The fact that a random person on Stack Overflow can't find a problem with it is worthless. Public encryption algorithms have been vetted by security professionals.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the post whilst you were writing this; because I realized I forgot to do just that! But I am glad I am in at least somewhat safe hands.

Comment: Just making sure you realize that `bytes(4)` returns `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'`, not `b'4'`.  This is fine.  Just making sure this is what you want.  

It is more common to build stream ciphers from things like AES.  So your first 32 bytes would be xor'ed with  encrypt(key, '00000001'), your next 32 bytes would be xor'ed with encrypt(key, '000000002'), etc.

Comment: you are correct. Thanks again for making sure that it will be able to encrypt stuff in the lifetime of this universe. Although it is still probably secure with the bug.

Comment: Please read my update.